# Exporting not working using jqueryTabs and TableTool

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, tabletools

I have a problem with my Exporting buttons: it works just for the first jQuery Table, but in other tables it doesn't work.

I have included all what needs to be included.

Here is an example for 2 jqueryTabs:

```
var jQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery2(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery2('#t1').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',

        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "csv",
                "xls",
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sPdfOrientation":"landscape",
                    "sPdfMessage": "Your custom message would go here."
                },
                "print"
            ]
        }
    });
    jQuery2('#t2').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "csv",
                "xls",
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf","sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                    "sPdfMessage": "Your custom message would go here."
                },
                "print"
            ]
        }
    } );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest calling the datatables separately without using the jQuery2 variable for both tables.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#t1').dataTable( { ... });
      $('#t2').dataTable( { ... });
 });
```

Comment: No i can't because i will have some conflicts with others jquery fonctions

Comment: Maybe try different variable names with direct initialization: http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/initialisation

Comment: please help me to find the solution